# Multiple sessions to call the API

Tags: api, session, login

I am writing an integration piece that basically listens for items on a queue and pushes data into SalesForce.

Currently for every message I login, perform the import, and logout.

Is this going to get me rate limited? Because messages can be processed at the same time am I ok to share a login session?

I know sessions last for up to 2 hours (currently) so should I share the session where I can, and just re-authenticate ever 2 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I have figured it out. The [login page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) says the following:

> Multiple client applications can log in using the same username argument. However, this increases your risk of getting errors due to query limits. A user can have up to 10 query cursors open at a time. If 10 QueryLocator cursors are open when a client application, logged in as the same user, attempts to open a new one, then the oldest of the 10 cursors is released. If the client application attempts to open the released query cursor, an error results.

Also

> There is a limit of 3600 calls to login() per user per hour. Exceeding this limit will result in a “Login Rate Exceeded” error.

So I think I need to ensure I re-use logins where I can.

Comment: The first point applies across all sessions, so there's little incentive to multitask with a single user account (e.g. multiple integration apps and/or multi-threaded apps). But you definitely want to avoid logging in any more frequently than necessary (mind you, 3600/hour is one *per second*, so you're not likely going to break that limit). Also, as an aside, the session *times out* after the given limit. If you're actively using your session at least once every two hours, it will roll indefinitely until explicitly logging out/timing out.